# GCS GoogleCredential

Tags: google-cloud-storage

My application has requirement to download file from GCS bucket.I am able to download files from GCS using StorageClient  DownloadObjects method. But performace is really slow. for 50MB file size it is taking 3-4 minutes and this time varies by hugh time difference. Please find sample code and let me know how can I improve downloading performance?

class Program
{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

```
    GoogleCredentials gcpCreds = new GoogleCredentials()
    {

        private_key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----PrivateKey-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
        client_email = "client_email",
        type = "service_account"
    };
    var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromJson(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gcpCreds));

    // var credentials= GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault();
    var storage = StorageClient.CreateAsync(credentials).Result;


    string localPath, directoryPath, localFileName, objectName, bucketName;
    directoryPath = "localpathstring";
    objectName = "SourceFileName";
    localFileName = objectName;
    localPath = directoryPath + "\\" + localFileName;
   bucketName="bucketName";

   FileStream fs = new FileStream(localPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

    //Code to download with progress bar
    DownloadObjectOptions option = new DownloadObjectOptions();

    using (fs)
    {
        var progress = new Progress<IDownloadProgress>(
             p => Console.WriteLine($"bytes: {p.BytesDownloaded}, status: {p.Status},"));
        storage.DownloadObject(bucketName, objectName, fs, option, progress);

        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The latency issue you are experiencing can come from either the application, the network (your own or Google’s), or the Cloud Storage service. To identify the root cause, here are some steps to follow:

1. Run [mtr](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mtr) to the Cloud Storage endpoint 2 times to determine if/where latency is observed on the network. Command example: `mtr -4 -n -r -c 10 www.googleapis.com`
2. [Download the file directly with gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects) to identify if the issue is on the application side.
3. Run a performance diagnostic with the [“perfdiag” gsutil command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/perfdiag) to determine any issue on Cloud Storage’s side. Command example: `gsutil perfdiag -o output.json gs://your-bucket`

If results are showing healthy metrics, then it would be worth trying to [download the file asynchronously](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClient.html#Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_StorageClient_DownloadObjectAsync_Google_Apis_Storage_v1_Data_Object_System_IO_Stream_Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_DownloadObjectOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_System_IProgress_Google_Apis_Download_IDownloadProgress__). Finally, here are some [tips for optimizing Cloud Storage performance](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/optimizing-your-cloud-storage-performance-google-cloud-performance-atlas).